# What's breaking the loop in middle pagination?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

I'm very confused. I have this code below to bypass my wordpress theme's when it comes to tags and subcategories which have posts that are linked to "quotes" category, and it's working fine until the middle of pagination. I'm unable to figure out why. Up until pagination 5, it's fine and then on pagination 6 and 7 and 8 it defaults to using the theme's loop, and then on 9 it resumes again normally using the loop I made.

```
<?php 
             $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                           array(
                          'taxonomy' => 'category',
                         'field' => 'slug',
                         'terms' => 'quotes',
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if(have_posts()):?>
           <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

           <h3> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a> 
        </h3>
            <?php endwhile;wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```